# Recommendation needed for drawer in react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

This is my first attempt in react-native project, Does react-native-navigation have drawer inbuild? If so please share the documentation link please? Am confused to use react-navigation or react-native-navigation.
My requirement is all about navigation, drawer, tabber for screens. 
Note: I need a native navigation to attract the users.

I used react-native-router-flux which have not much documentation but have quite good answers for all the workarounds. Also its not maintained now. SO indeed to select a new one.

Comment: Please look this, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

Comment: @JebinBenny , I think we all getting confused of react navigation and react native navigation.

Comment: You have to follow react navigation thats pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, I should say that I always use react-Navigation and I like it. To hightlight one of my reasons I should say that "Being a JS-based navigator allows React Navigation to integrate smoothly with any of the third-party libraries, while RNN may suffer from libraries that are tightly coupled with native platforms or need to be wrapped around the whole app." You can check this link:

https://blog.logrocket.com/react-navigation-vs-react-native-navigation-which-is-right-for-you-3d47c1cd1d63/

For the drawer, I highly recommended this one, because it give you any option that you want and it is working perfectly on both iOS and android for me, while others always make troubles for me in one of mentioned platforms.

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink

Also if you want other elements and tools with a good performance, check this link:

https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/overview.html

I hope I could help you.